# GraphQL resolve more than one interface

Tags: graphql, graph-databases, graphql-js

I am working with a native graph database.

My data objects are composed from many smaller sets of attributes, and I would like to be able to query all of them at once without adding extra artificial layers in my schema.  The attributes are very well defined, but the composition of them is not.

Assume it is easy (trivial) for me to output this object from a query:

```
{
  "name": "Zapdos",
  "wingspan": 40,
  "airspeed": 120,
  "maxVoltage": 100000000
}
```

Assume that the `wingspan` and `airVelocity` properties come from a `FlyingType` attribute, and `maxVoltage` from an `ElectricType` attribute.  These and other attributes are well defined.  Other pokemon may mix and match attributes that apply to them, and defining all combinations of them might not make sense.

### Ideal Scenario

Is it possible to run the following query and get data in the same format back?

Would `graphql-js` have to handle an array returned by `resolveType` function?  Does the default `resolveType` function stop at the first true value from calling `isTypeOf`?

```
query {
  Pokemon(name: "Zapdos") {
    name

    ... on isFlyingType {
      wingspan
      airVelocity
    }

    ... on isElectricType {
      maxVoltage
    }
  }
}
```

### what is probably the case

Do I actually need to build a new type with *everything* that I need?  I have many attributes that compose my data, and that would mean A LOT of types to account every combination of interfaces. E.g. must I do the following?

```
type FlyingElectricPokemon implements isPokemon, isFlyingType, isElectricType {
  name: String!
  wingspan: Int
  airVelocity: Int
  maxVoltage: Int
}
```

```
query {
  Pokemon(name: "Zapdos") {
    name

    ... on FlyingElectricPokemon {
      wingspan
      airVelocity
      maxVoltage
    }
  }
}
```

Am I just fighting too hard to avoid the strong typing of GraphQL on my rather weakly-typed graph data?

### Work around but with added complexity

I would prefer to avoid the following add complexity:

```
type Query {
  Pokemon(name: String): Pokemon
}

type Pokemon {
  name: String!
  attributes: [isAttribute!]
}

interface isAttribute {
  type: String!
}

type FlyingType implements isAttribute {
  type: String!
  wingspan: Int
}

type ElectricType implements isAttribute {
  type: String!
  maxVoltage: Int
}
```

```
query {
  Pokemon(name: "Zapdos") {
    name
    attributes {
      ... on FlyingType {
        wingspan
        airVelocity
      }
      ... on ElectricType {
        maxVoltage
      }
    }
  }
}
```

requiring data in the following format

```
{
  "name": "Zapdos",
  "attributes": [
    { "type": "flying", "wingspan": 40 },
    { "type": "electric", "maxVoltage": 100000000 }
  ]
}
```

This latter bit I actually got to work on [Launchpad](https://launchpad.graphql.com/0vw33q8m55).

Comment: I can only recommend grouping relatable types into interfaces and then using unions to bridge any gaps. When given a choice I go with unions, since they don't take as much overhead to reason about. I can't give specific recommendations since you don't give the whole API, but it looks a bit awkward. Sometimes revisiting the 1000 foot picture is helpful (if you aren't too invested already)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's an interesting scenario. I don't think vanilla GraphQL really offers a vehicle to achieve what you describe. The problem is that, in the end, any object being returned has to have exactly one type. `__resolveType` cannot return an array, and even if you declare a `__isTypeof` for multiple types that will evaluate true for a given object, only the first one that evaluates true will be associated with that particular object.

At the end of the day, if your intent is to return a subset of possible attributes (based on the Pokemon's type or types), the simplest solution may be to just make all possible attributes into fields of the `Pokemon` type and not worry about trying to implement interfaces around the types. This achieves the flat data structure you want in your response. The biggest downside is you will have a possibly large number of null fields returned as part of the response.

You can also look into something like [graphql-s2s](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-s2s), which supports type inheritance and generics.

Comment: Thank you. I also realized that I wouldn’t be able to create mutations without polymorphic input types either. I am now looking at how to query the groups of properties (each an edge on the graph) into an array of attributes.  I can then create a mutation for each attribute, passing the same ID to multiple attributes to update the parent object (node on the graph). Surprisingly enough, the input object for such a mutation should work well for the DBs language.